# How to set time in nanoseconds?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, clock, satellite

I have a Raspberry Pi with a GPS module connected to it. Since all GPS satellites have very precise atomic clocks on them, I would like to synchronize the Pi's clock to the satellites' clocks. I know how to get the date and time from the satellites, and set my Pi's time with:

`sudo date -s "MAR 14 2016 14:53:09"`

But that is only accurate to the seconds, I would like to at least get milliseconds, but I would prefer nanoseconds.

I know that `date +%s%N` returns time in nanoseconds.

How do I set the time in nanoseconds?

Comment: How are you connecting it to the Pi? USB?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yep, serial to USB adapter.

Comment: Too slow, no better resolution than getting it via NTP. The capability of doing that is also dependent on the brand, please post it to see if someone answers.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the converter or the GPS module? All I know is that the module runs at a baudrate of 9600.

Comment: If it's accurate time you're after, suggest you look into PTP - http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the time the data reaches your PC via the USB/RS232 interface, the resolution and accuracy won't be any good. At the end of the day, without dedicated equipment, it is better to stay with NTP.

From this [GPS synchronization tutorial](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/GPS-time.html)

> There are many cheap GPS receivers available in the market. Most of
>   them use either an RS232, or USB connection to send their information
>   to the attached computer. Although the clock inside the receiver
>   itself runs with an accuracy of some nanoseconds, the transfer of the
>   data to the computer causes such a large delay, that in practice it is
>   not possible to synchronize the clock of the local computer with that
>   signal with an accuracy of better than a handful of milliseconds. That
>   kind of accuracy can also be obtained by connecting to a freely
>   available NTP time server over the internet. Only GPS devices which
>   have a special fast and accurate synchronization method with the
>   computer can be used as a time synchronization device. The most
>   expensive and accurate way to do this is to use a GPS receiver which
>   fits in a local PCI or PCIex slot of the computer. But these cards are
>   very expensive and not widely available. The other solution is to use
>   the slow and inaccurate RS232 or USB interface to send general data
>   and do the time synchronization with a pulse.

As @dfc correctly points out, RS232 with PPS does the job. However, the device has to support it.

> On most GPS devices with pulse capability, the pulse is sent once
>   every second, starting at the beginning of every new second. This is
>   why these GPS devices are often referred to as GPS with PPS, for pulse
>   per second.
>
> Unfortunately there are not a large number of GPS receivers which have
>   the extra PPS output. I am using Garmin GPS receivers in Kazakhstan
>   for my tourism activities and I have therefore first looked at the
>   available devices from this manufacturer. Currently there are two
>   Garmin GPS receivers which may be used with a direct connection with a
>   computer: the Garmin GPS 16x LVS and the Garmin GPS 18x LVC. They both
>   work on a supply voltage of +5 Volt which is directly available from a
>   computer, they both send the general data in NMEA protocol over an
>   RS232 interface and they both have a PPS output.

Comment: RS232 with PPS is not slow and innacurate.

Comment: Indeed, I had not added it for the answer. thanks.